# Problem with Redux in SPFX

Tags: spfx, react

I am currently practising some Redux and now trying to implement it in a simple SPFx Counter webpart but I am facing problems.

Here is the Webpart which is a simple counter:
[image]

When I click the 'Increment' button, which I am currently testing with Redux; I get following error in the console:
[image]

Here is my code for the parent component, **ReduxCounter.tsx:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './ReduxCounter.module.scss';
import { IReduxCounterProps } from './IReduxCounterProps';
import  Counter  from '../containers/Counter';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Store, createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';

import counterReducer from '../store/reducers/counter';
import { IReduxStateProps } from '../store/IReduxStateProps';
import { increment } from '../store/actions/counter';

export default class ReduxCounter extends React.Component<IReduxCounterProps, {}> {
  private store: Store<IReduxStateProps>; //Initialize store
  /**
   * Added constructor in order to initiate the store object
   */
  constructor(props: IReduxCounterProps) {
    super(props);
    this.store = createStore(
      counterReducer //Create Store
    );
    this.store.dispatch(increment());
    this.store.subscribe(this.render); //subscribe
  }
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IReduxCounterProps> {
    //
    return (
      <Provider store={this.store}>
      <div className={ styles.reduxCounter }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <div className={ styles.row }>
            <span className={ styles.title }>Redux Counter</span>
            <Counter value={1} description="TEST" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Component/container that I want to connect to Redux, **Counter.tsx:**

```
import { DefaultButton, isRelativeUrl, values } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
import * as React from 'react';
import { IReduxCounterProps } from '../components/IReduxCounterProps';
import Output from '../components/CounterOutput/Output';
import { ICounterState } from './ICounterState';
//redux related
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { IReduxStateProps } from '../store/IReduxStateProps';
import counterReducer from '../store/reducers/counter';

class Counter extends React.Component<IReduxStateProps, ICounterState> {
    /**
     *
     */
    constructor(props: IReduxStateProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            counter: 0
        }       
    }

    // private counterOnIncrement() {
    //     // console.log("Counter Increment");
    //     // this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 });
    //     // console.log(this.state.counter);        
    // }

    // private counterOnDecrement() {
    //     // console.log("Counter Decrement");
    //     // this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter - 1 });
    // }
    
    public render() : React.ReactElement<IReduxCounterProps> {
        console.log(mapStateToProps);
        
        return(
            <div>
                <Output value={this.props.counter} description="test" />
                <DefaultButton text="Increment" onClick={this.props.increment} />
                <DefaultButton text="Decrement" onClick={() => this.props.counter} />
            </div>
        );
        
        
    }
}

const counterState = new Counter({ description: 'test', value: 0, counter: 0, increment: '' }).state.counter;
console.log(counterState);

const mapStateToProps = (state: ICounterState, myProps: IReduxCounterProps): IReduxStateProps => {
    return{
        counter: counterState,
        description: '',
        value: 1, 
        increment: ''
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        increment: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' }),
        decrement: () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' }),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter);
```

Here are the Redux related files:
counter.ts (actions):

```
//action
export function increment() {
    return{
        type: 'INCREMENT'
    }
}

export function decrement() {
    return{
        type: 'DECREMENT'
    }
}
```

**counter.ts (reducer):**

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
    counter: 0
}

const counterReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    let newState = (<any>Object).assign({}, state); //Create an JavaScript Object for new state
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.INCREMENT:
            counter: state.counter + 1;

        case actionTypes.DECREMENT:
            newState.counter = state.counter - 1;
            return newState;
             
        default:
            break;
    }
    console.log(state);
    return state;
}

export default counterReducer;
```

Would appreciate if someone could please help me out with this issue.
Thank you in advance.